# Can't Connect and Input field to the to the Function/Class

Tags: swift, function, struct, swiftui, textfield

We have a large function/class that is outside the struct where we have our input-field (TextField value). For some reason, we can't connect the field to the function.

**What we are trying to accomplish:** Have the Algorithm/function that we've created, be used upon the click of the button, and then used withing MapView. Making the variables globally accessible

**What We've tried so far:** Pasting the entire class within the MenuTabView Struct, @EnviromentalObject, Simple callout of the function in the first snippet of code.

Here is our current HStack View

```
  HStack {​
            Button(action: {​
                // FIXME: Here should be some action for calculating the route -> hopefully with light data
                MapView.plotRoute(sourceLat: 52.38916893852631, sourceLon: 13.119924894109332, destinationLat: 52.395251383040865, destinationLon: 13.128239742045292)
            }​) {​
                Text("Find Route")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .bold()
            }​.padding()
        }​
```

Here are our MapView: UIViewRepresentable variables {

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var directions: [String]
    @Binding var checkpoints: [Checkpoint]
    var mapView = MKMapView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
```

Here are the Variables that we would like to make accessible "everywhere"

```
// The State for the directions display
@State private var showDirections = false
// Set the coordinates for the test checkpoints
@State var checkpoints: [Checkpoint] = [
  Checkpoint(title: "Test Lamp", coordinate: .init(latitude: 52.387797, longitude: 13.119534))
]
```

I know the code doesn't help much, but unfortunately, I can't post all of the HStack and the Class/function here.

Here is the Error:

> Instance member 'plotRoute' cannot be used on type 'MapView'; did you
> mean to use a value of this type instead? MapTabView.swift

error is shown by Swift when we tried to call-out a part of the function

[image: error is shown by Swift when we tried to call-out a part of the function]

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried declaring the variables as static, or perhaps even saving them to UserDefaults if they're really giving you trouble.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `plotRoute` is an instance method of `MapView`, but you are trying to call it on the type rather than the instance.

If the method really is a type method, you should change its declaration to `static func plotRoute(...` and then you'll be able to call it as `MapView.plotRoute...`.

If the method uses instance properties of `MapView`, then you need to create a `MapView` instance inside your `View` and call the method on that.